# How to fetch name and value from below json data

Tags: javascript, bash

I have below JSON data

```
[{"name":"fname","value":"surbhi"},{"name":"lname","value":"singhal"}]
```

then how to fetch name and value fields data
I am new in JSON so please help me out

Comment: Parse the JSON first

Comment: Take a look the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem clearly.

Comment: Are you working in javascript, or bash? You have both tagged.

Comment: i am working in bash

Comment: @SaeedShamloo I want to fetch the name field from data

Comment: `[{name: "fname"}, {name:"lname"}]` is this your expected result?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{ "name": "fname", "value": "surbhi" }, { "name": "lname", "value": "singhal" }]

var i

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    document.write(data[i].name + ":<br>")
    document.write(data[i].value + ":<br>")
}
```